# How can i solve IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

Tags: python, pandas, index-error

```
def get_live_rsi(bybit, symbol):

    data = bybit.fetch_ohlcv(
        symbol=symbol,
        timeframe=timeframe,
        since=None,
        limit=limit
    )

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data = data,
        columns=['datetime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
    )
    df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], unit='ms')
    df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
    
    closedata = df['close']
    
    delta = closedata.diff()
    
    ups, downs = delta.copy(), delta.copy()
    ups[ups < 0] = 0
    downs[downs > 0] = 0

    period = 2
    au = ups.ewm(com = period-1, min_periods = period).mean()
    ad = downs.abs().ewm(com = period-1, min_periods = period).mean()
    
    rs = au/ad
    
    live_rsi = np.array((100 - (100/(1+rs))))[9]
    
    
    return live_rsi
```

It runs fine for the first 10 mins, and suddenly this error pops up

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Arrays in almost all programming languages (except VB 6) are zero-based. The index of the last item in a 9-item array is 8

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `DataFrame` has `9` rows and at the end, you're trying to access the last item on the `np.array` to get the `live_rsi`. The thing is that the index starts at `0` so the last one should be `8` for `9` items.

Instead of `9` use `8` or `-1` like below. Negative indices are interpreted as counting from the end of the array.

```py
live_rsi = np.array((100 - (100/(1+rs))))[-1]
```